# Symfony make:auth command

Tags: php, authentication, web, new-project, symfony6

I create a website with symfony 6 and I'd like to add an authentication system.

I see that `symfony console make:auth` command exist, but I can't use it with Symfony 6 ?

I got this error : `[ERROR] MakerBundle only supports the new authenticator based security system. See https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html`.

Someone has a tutorial to create login forms and registration form (cause I tryed to use documentation and for registration form I got another error, one of (Exception) class is not founded...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check at security bundle config file located at `config/packages/security.yaml`. Make sure `enable_authenticator_manager` setting is there.

If the value is `false`, set it to `true`.
If none, add it under `security` section.

```yaml
security:
    # add line below
    enable_authenticator_manager: true
```

Then execute `make:auth` again